# Kivy Recycle View Dynamic widget height causing lagging scrolling and jumping

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

So I am making an app that requires me to load a list of custom widgets`(MDCards)` into a `RecycleView`. Each MDcard will contain two labels and a checkbox. The text can be any size and thus the MDCard has to change its height based on the text that it contains. Here is the part in the kv file that deals with this...NOTE: the text i am adding now is temporary to allow me to create different cards with progressively larger heights.

**Custom MDCARD Widget**

```
<IndivualReminderElementBlueprint@MDCard>:
md_bg_color:218/255,68/255,83/255,1
size_hint: 1, None
text: ''
Label:
    on_size: root.height = self.height
    size_hint: 1, None
    text_size: root.width, None
    size: self.texture_size
    text: root.text
```

**The kv code for the RecycleView class**

```
<ListViewBlueprint>:
viewclass: 'IndivualReminderElementBlueprint'
data: [{"text": f"{i} {'test'*i**2}"} for i in range(20)]
RecycleBoxLayout:
    id: container
    default_size: None, None
    default_size_hint: 1, None
    size_hint_y: None
    height: self.minimum_height
    orientation: 'vertical'
    spacing:'20dp'
```

I am aware that this jerkiness in the scrolling is caused because the size of the widgets is calculated as the user scrolls down which also causes the scroll position to jump randomly. I also looked into this issue posted on Github https://github.com/kivy/kivy/issues/6582 . But i am unable to understand the code at the end or if it will actually fix this problem? I was also wondering if there was any other way to fix this problem? Thanks :)